# Find the location of hive-site.xml in java code

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I want to pass the location of hive-site.xml file in my java program.

What is the best way to find out the location of this file automatically in java code?

I do not want to hard code the path to `/etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml` for cloudera distibution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Hadoop `Configuration` constructors search for "blahblah-site.xml" config files in **directories** present in **CLASSPATH**. If it doesn't find them, then it reverts to hard-coded "default" values, without any warning (!).

So make sure that the CLASSPATH contains the appropriate directories on the front, e.g. `/etc/hadoop/conf/:/etc/hive/conf/:/etc/tez/conf/:...`

Then the only thing you have to do in your Java code is to check that critical properties are set up with something else that hard-coded defaults (and raise a *PleaseSetupProperClasspathYouSuckerException* if it's not the case).

Answer (score 0):

- Set the HIVE_HOME path as /etc/hive/bin in the system environment variable and get it in java code as follows,

**String path = System.getenv("HIVE_HOME");**