# Do we need to run hiveserver2 on our client machine to access hive metastore?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-java to access hive metastore. On my machine only spark is installed and nothing else. I don't have hadoop directory or Hive folder. I have created `hive-site.xml`, `hdfs-site.xml`,`core-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` inside `spark/conf` directory. My hive metastore is setup on another machine which is a part of hadoop cluster and is the namenode. I can access hive metastore from `spark/bin/beeline` and `spark/bin/spark-shell` on my desktop, but when I try to access hive-metastore from java-api, I get `metastore_db` folder and `derby.log` file created in my project, which means I can't access hive metastore.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://bigdata-namenode:9000/user/hive/warehouse")
                .config("mapred.input.dir.recursive", true)
                .config("hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories", true)
                .config("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", true)
                .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();
spark.sql("show databases").show();
```

when I start thrift server on my desktop (i.e client machine) I get this log [thriftserver.log](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25288757/)
which says `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` is set to `my local file system path` i.e not hdfs where is actual warehouse located.
[/spark/conf/core-site.xml](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25288787/)
[/spark/conf/hive-site.xml](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/25288791/)

Comment: Put the directory containing your Hadoop conf files in the CLASSPATH so that the Hadoop libs find them. That's one of the many things that `spark-shell` and `spark-submit` shells do.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out a while ago. But if you put this as an answer.I would accept it as it may help others.

Comment: It's by no means a "new" issue, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33901667/find-the-location-of-hive-site-xml-in-java-code/33916731